# cannot find AudioEngine in scope

Tags: audiokit

Briefly, I have installed AudioKit XCFramework, imported AudioKit into a simple class and, as per migration guide, tried to create an instance of Audio engine instead of the old 4.0 AudioKit singleton.

Steps
1: made frameworks folder , pasted AudioKit XCFramework into it
2: embedded and signed AudioKit in project settings
3: updated other linker flags to include -lc++
4: updated framework search paths to include path to Audiokit
5: Wrote simple class with code below

```
import AudioKit
class AkStart {
var mix = AKMixer()
init(){
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    engine.output = mix
    engine.start()
}
```

}

I get an error preventing compilation reading: "cannot find 'AudioEngine' in scope"
my Xcode version is 12.3, Im using SwiftUI, and AudioKit XCFramework AudioKit version at time of writing 5.0
Are there additional input statements or steps in the framework installation that I also need to include?

Comment: Not answering your question, but I am curious if you can answer my question, which is why use the XC Framework at all?

Comment: basically it was the top of the list on the downloads page is I just figured Id give it a go first, now that having been said, I also tried the package manager route, both v5-develop and v5-main but I get "An unknown error occurred. HTTP parser error: stream ended at an unexpected time (-1)
"

Comment: what's the best way for an install into a swiftUI app on XCOde 12.3?, I cant help feeling Im missing something really really basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all of your questions would be answered by watching the Office Hours I've posted to YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLLYNAal3aJpaFl4WluRCvw

And feel free to join in the next one. I post the link on the AudioKitMan twitter feed.

Comment: Overall I think the best approach to getting the AudioEngine running in an app is in the first of the videos in the series you linked just there, i.e : use Xcode package manager, , so Im marking this as the accepted answer, although my package download keeps being cut short by what I think is my providers default network settings(not an AudioKit Problem), I had to clone a local AudioKit with --depth 1 to reduce the file size, upload my own GitHub package from that and PM install it that way and I now have access to AudioEngine